# A scheduling tool like calendly for mobile apps (flutter)

Tags: flutter, resource-scheduling

I'm looking for something like calendly for a flutter mobile app. Calendly has API:s but they are really not meant for a mobile app and don't allow for creating and calling events.

Anything you can recommend? I'm trying out timekit atm but it's pretty expensive.

The app is for customers who want to buy and schedule a time from an expert. So basically there are around 20 experts listed in the app, and a user should be able to see their availability, book a session and be able to cancel/rechedule it later.

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar. Did you had any luck finding the appropriate solution for you ?